# How to reset the types of the notification?

Tags: ios, swift

I used to register my notification using the code below.

```
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Sound, .Badge], categories: UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()?.categories)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
```

Now I want to cancel the .Sound notification type. It seems I can not use

```
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge], categories: UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()?.categories)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
```

to do that. Any solutions to close the sound of my remote notification?

Comment: Sure you can. Calling registerUserNotificationSettings with a new user settings object replaces the previous settings request.

Comment: You see my code above . Any problem?UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings() gets the same notification settings as before.

Comment: Try just passing nil to categories

Comment: It can add a new type of notification. But it can not delete a type of notification.